# Used storage of a pvc via api

Tags: java, kubernetes

I'm trying to get `space used` from a PVC that is mounted to a pod via the java kubernetes-client by fabric8io. Till now I've not found a way to get this metric. So the question how can I display metrics like:

```
pvcs: [{ 
  name: pvc-abc,
  requests: 500Mi,
  usedStorage: ????   // <---- looking for this metric
}]
```

By using the `kubernetesClient.persistentVolumeClaims()` shows only the capacity of a PVC

> PersistentVolumeClaim(apiVersion=v1, kind=PersistentVolumeClaim,..... capacity={storage=500Mi}, conditions=[], phase=Bound, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={})

Comment: please provide what cloud provider you use or it is bare-metal cluster?

Comment: Its bare-metal, k8s created via Rancher

Answer (score 0):

> PVC is an abstraction which represents a request for a storage and simply **doesn't store** such information **as disk usage**. As a higher level abstraction it doesn't care at all how the underlying storage is used by its consumer.

Since you are using java library using kubernetes-client, see the example code below:

```
try {
    String result = apiInstance.connectGetNamespacedPodExec(name, namespace, command, container, stderr, stdin, stdout, tty);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    System.err.println("Exception when calling CoreV1Api#connectGetNamespacedPodExec");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where the command will be: `["/bin/sh"]` and args: `["-c", "while true; do du -sh /data; sleep 10;done"]`. It runs a simple bash script - an infinite while loop, which prints out current disk usage to the standard output it can be read with kubectl logs without a need of using kubectl exec and attaching to the Pod. You can modify the command whatever you want, if you don't need a loop and want to execute it just once.

Here is the full example code for your reference:

```java
// Import classes:
//import io.kubernetes.client.ApiClient;
//import io.kubernetes.client.ApiException;
//import io.kubernetes.client.Configuration;
//import io.kubernetes.client.auth.*;
//import io.kubernetes.client.apis.CoreV1Api;

ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

// Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
ApiKeyAuth BearerToken = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("BearerToken");
BearerToken.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
// Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. "Token" (defaults to null)
//BearerToken.setApiKeyPrefix("Token");

CoreV1Api apiInstance = new CoreV1Api();
String name = "name_example"; // String | name of the Pod
String namespace = "namespace_example"; // String | object name and auth scope, such as for teams and projects
String command = "command_example"; // String | Command is the remote command to execute. argv array. Not executed within a shell.
String container = "container_example"; // String | Container in which to execute the command. Defaults to only container if there is only one container in the pod.
Boolean stderr = true; // Boolean | Redirect the standard error stream of the pod for this call. Defaults to true.
Boolean stdin = true; // Boolean | Redirect the standard input stream of the pod for this call. Defaults to false.
Boolean stdout = true; // Boolean | Redirect the standard output stream of the pod for this call. Defaults to true.
Boolean tty = true; // Boolean | TTY if true indicates that a tty will be allocated for the exec call. Defaults to false.
try {
    String result = apiInstance.connectGetNamespacedPodExec(name, namespace, command, container, stderr, stdin, stdout, tty);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    System.err.println("Exception when calling CoreV1Api#connectGetNamespacedPodExec");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, if you want to use only fabric8io library, then [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#kubectl-java-equivalents) you can find the equivalents for Kubectl commands:

`kubectl exec my-pod -- ls /` --> [PodExecEquivalent.java](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/kubectl/equivalents/PodExecEquivalent.java)

---

Extending the answer by replying to the comment under the answer:

if we don't talk about java and its code (I'm not good at) and we will discuss on Kubernetes decisions, then we can do a deployment of a single pod to have all PVCs used metrics in one place.

You can create a sidecar running next to `nginx` container that runs that simple bash script - an infinite while loop (it can be single run command, with no loop), which only function is to mount the same volume and check its current usage and prints out current disk usage to the standard output:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: media
      - name: busybox
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do du -sh /data; sleep 10;done"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: media
```

It can be easily read using `kubectl logs <pod_name> <container_name>` without a need of using `kubectl exec` and attaching to the `Pod`:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-deployment-56bb5c87f6-dqs5h busybox
20.0K   /data
20.0K   /data
20.0K   /data
```

You can apply it by `kubectl apply -f`

I guess it can be also used more effectively to configure some sort of monitoring of disk usage.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. So if I understood it right, there isn't an easy way for getting usage of all pvcs in one NS. Do you have an idea would one check the metric of all pvcs in one NS. There are `RWO` So mounting it to a temporary pod and doing the `du` command would not be possible !?

Comment: @imalik8088, extended the answer replying to your question here

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor not yet, or better to to say. I've a more dynamic namespace where deployments are creating dynamic pods with a pvc and I need to analyse these pvcs. If I've some updates, I'll update my question with some resources.